# jQuery Mobile 1.2 PhoneGap/Cordova 2.1 Android 4.0.3 Error loading page

Tags: android, cordova, jquery-mobile, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, cordova-2.0.0

I've read up on the "chromium error: -6" and get the issues with url parameters in the android webview in 3.0+.

On startup, my application checks to see if you're authenticated, and if not, executes a $.mobile.changePage to the login page. This fails and throws up the "error loading page" message from jQuery Mobile. I'm not passing parameters in the querystring, so the only thing I can think that would be getting in the way is the hash manipulation jQM uses for ajax navigation. So, I made one change and turned off ajax navigation by setting $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false. My page loaded correctly.

So my question is: is there some other way I can configure things so that I can enable ajax navigation? Or is there a patch to PhoneGap/Cordova 2.1 or jQuery Mobile 1.2 that fixes this?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the  `rel="external"`  attribute as described on the doc pages?
See [here](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/page-links.html) - particularly the "Linking without Ajax" and "Linking within a multi-page document"

Comment: Yes, I've considered that, but it's essentially a mechanism for a one off non-ajax navigation, which causes a full page refresh. I've got that already by turning off ajax navigation across the whole app. I don't want to do that.